# Expressing the idea of killing, finishing/knocking someone off with the phrasal verb "to blip off"

Tags: idioms, slang, phrasal-verbs, idiom-meaning, euphemisms

Somehow I was in the knowledge of the fact that the phrasal verb "to blip off" could be used to convey the idea of "to bump off", "to kill", "to knock off" and so on.

But on Ngram I found that the frequency of the phrase's usage was holding out for 0%.

At the same time on that very site there was one among the examples: "*Not a button man by trade, nonetheless I'd heard he'd blipped off at least two men and left their remains in the high timber west of town.*" ("Hand of Glory" by Laird Barron, page 385)

Is "to blip off" used, after all, in the meaning of "to kill", "to finish off", "to bump off" etc (maybe at certain localities)?

Comment: There are a lot of metaphors sometimes used for killing in various ways, eg snuff out, take out, wipe out, blow away, knock off, pull the plug. Some become common enough to make dictionaries, but I don't think "blip off" is there yet. NB Please cite quotations, post links, and give sources.

Comment: @Stuart F My quotation is from "Hand of Glory" by Laird Barron, page 385. If you happen to look it up, please, render me your oppinion. (to me, a non-native speaker, "to blip off" seems well-taken and deserving to take on as an idiom)

Comment: Any causative verb involving rapid movement of the object can be used in a pejorative phrasal verb, many  with _off_. But it's just one more oddity of phrasal verbs, not anything special with a special term for it.

Answer (score 1):

*Blip off* is a euphemism for 'to kill' used and originated in hardboiled slang. [Hardboiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardboiled) fiction is a American crime fiction with tough, unsentimantel, violent style of writing; and used slangy dialogue. It started in mid-1920s, was popular in pulp magazines between 1930s-1950s.

> Blip off: To kill
>
> <sub>*Twists, Slugs and Roscoes: A Glossary of Hardboiled Slang* - [miskatonic.org](https://www.miskatonic.org/slang.html)</sub>

It appears to be a metaphor for monitoring device blips where they vanish when the machine stops working. It is also an analogy to an electrocardiogram heart monitor  where it flatlines (the blips stop) when the heart stops working (no electrical activity: *asystole*).

> **blip off** *American* to kill 
>  *Blips* indicate that an oscilloscope or other monitoring equipment is working. They vanish if the instrument malfunctions and switched off.
>
> *[Dictionary of Euphemisms](https://books.google.es/books?id=_tSNa4kBx2IC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=%22blip%20off%22%20kill&source=bl&ots=huZ3kTdDEi&sig=ACfU3U2iQ-QFi4y6Mif6yvthmKb7415BIQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjntIPJhMv5AhUhgs4BHVaBCrwQ6AF6BAgbEAM#v=onepage&q=%22blip%20off%22%20kill&f=false)* By R. W. Holder